# "Out of bound iterator" with an empty set

Tags: c++, iterator, segmentation-fault, set, c++17

I get a segmentation fault in this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main() {
    std::set<int> st;
    auto rf = --st.end();
    std::cout << "Size of the set is: " << (int) st.size() << std::endl;

    if ( (int) st.size() > 0) { // size of st is zero here
        int foo = (*rf);  // rf is out bound
        std::cout << "foo: " << foo << std::endl;
    }
}
```

As `st` is empty, the `if` condition will never be true, whatever the `rf` is out of bound. If I comment out the `if` block, then the program runs fine.

I have tried it with an `std::vector` also and it runs fine.

Why do I get a segmentation fault? Why the 'always false if condition with invalid statement' affects on running of the code?

Compiling with:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wfloat-equal -pedantic -std=c++17 -Wconversion -lm test.cpp
```

Comment: You can't do `--sr.end();` for an empty container. I doesn't matter if you dereference the iterator or not. You have undefined behavior, and any change can set it off without explanation.

Comment: Use a debugger to catch the crash. It will not happen where you think it happens.

Comment: If `std::set` is empty, then `begin == end` is true, which means decrementing `end` makes no sense and smells of undefined behavior.

Comment: Guys, don't answer in the comment ;)

Comment: As an aside, if you want something pointing to the final element, and don't care about it's type besides being a `BidirectionalIterator`, you can use `st.rbegin()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is undefined behavior:

```
std::set<int> st;
auto rf = --st.end();
```

Since `st` is empty, `st.begin() == st.end()` and decrementing either one of those two (and same) iterators is ill-formed.

> I have tried it with vector also and runs fine.

This is one of the most pernicious consequence of UB: it might look like it is OK. It is not.